# case statement for each row manipulations

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Hi I have a table which has an ID and status.One ID can have multiple status but I have to pick status based on the conditions.

If ID 1 has Approved, Later,Modified I should Pick Approved and if the ID has only approved then Pick only Approved.But the case statement I got is not doing per ID.It is changing the overall data based on status.Please advise

```
  select ID,
CASE
    WHEN status = 'Approved'
    AND status IN(
        'Modified',
        'Later'
    ) THEN 'Partial Modified'
    WHEN status = 'Approved' THEN 'Approved'
    when status IN('Modified','Edited') THEN 'Modified'
    else status
END status group by ID,Status
```

Comment: can you show the full statement being used?

Comment: I think you typed the AND clause of your first WHEN incorrectly. Are you meaning to make a second comparison after the "status" equal to x?

Comment: I'm not following the logic but a CASE expression (not statement) that looks at a column value can only look at it at a single point in time. It can't be approved *and* later/modified, it can only be one of those values. Instead of a word problem can you please show sample data (including at least one row representing each possible outcome) and desired results?

Comment: Each ID can have a max of 3 status at a time and we have to pick one as per the conditions above and that status repeats for that ID in the status column.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with an ordering condition in `row_number`.

```
select top 1 with ties *
from tbl 
order by row_number() over(partition by id order by case when status='Approved' then 1 
                                                         when status='Modified' then 2
                                                    else 3 end)
```

Comment: This is good, but How do we apply case in order to pick the status according to the conditions.The same status repeats for the same ID as final status

Comment: @user1046415 Again, word problems, can you please see my comment above...

Comment: @Vamsi Prabhala,@AaronBertrand  Please find the data in the SQL Fiddler..Output should have ID 1 - Partially Modified, 2-Partially Modified,3-Modified,4-Approved .. with same number of rows as in table ..

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an aggregation, so something like this:

```
(CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Approved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
      THEN 'Approved'
      WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Modified' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
      THEN 'Modified'
      ELSE MAX(status)
 END)
```

Of course, you can also do this using window functions:

```
(CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Approved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) > 0
      THEN 'Approved'
      WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Modified' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) > 0
      THEN 'Modified'
      ELSE MAX(status) OVER (PARTITION BY id)
 END)
```

Comment: One ID has three status but I have to pick only one based on conditions above.Ex: If it has approved and modified and draft I have to say ' partial Modified'.. but your query is giving approved as output when there is approved

Comment: The ID will have same status repeated as final status based on the conditions

Comment: @user1046415 . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you actually ask.  Your question says *NOTHING* about "partial Modified".  I would suggest that you ask *another* question that has a more thorough description of your problem, with better sample data.  Modifying your question is unfair to the people who have answered it, because it will render valid answers invalid.